# Breeze zStorage adds up data to the old data

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm working on an Angular project which uses Breeze and zStorage to manage data. When I try to refresh data, it pushes the new data to the storage without removing the old data.

```
 function getAll(forceRemote, page, size, nameFilter) {
        var self = this;
        // Only return a page worth of devices
        var take = size || 20;
        var skip = page ? (page - 1) * size : 0;

        if (self.zStorage.areItemsLoaded(entityName) && !forceRemote) {
            // Get the page of Peripherals from local cache
            return self.$q.when(getByPage());
        }

        // Load all devices to cache via remote query
        return EntityQuery.from('Devices')               
            .orderBy(orderBy)
            .toType(entityName)
            .using(self.manager).execute()
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .catch(self._queryFailed);


        function querySucceeded(data) {                
            self.zStorage.areItemsLoaded(entityName, true);
            self.zStorage.save();
            self.log('Retrieved [Devices] from remote data source', data.results.length, true);
            return getByPage();
        }

        function getByPage() {
            var predicate = null;

            if (nameFilter) {
                predicate = _devicePredicate(nameFilter);
            }

            var devices = EntityQuery.from(entityName)
                .where(predicate)
                .orderBy(orderBy)
                .toType(entityName)
                .take(take).skip(skip)
                .using(self.manager)
                .executeLocally();

            return devices;
        }
    }
```

I don't know whether the problem is with my configuration or the zStorage.

Answer (score 0):

It was my own mistake in producing new GUID in the breeze controller, breeze has become very powerful tool for entity management in the client side.